# I have been out of the MTG loop for the past year and i'm wondering how I can get back in

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I picked up MTG around the start or mid last year. I purchased a Rakdos intro deck, and was pleased with it. I pushed some friends into MTG as well and they as well got a deck. For Christmas last year, I bought my self a Theros fat pack, along with a single booster. I now have an extremely small collection of cards from RTR to Theros. Throughout this year, I have done absolutely nothing to do with MTG. My friends barely play and I haven't had the money to buy any more MTG related items apart from sleeves for my crap Izzet deck(now dismantled) and a proxy Red Deck Wins modern deck.

My friends and I have now lgs or place to group up to play as we are all very busy with school and other stuff.

I was wondering how I could get back into MTG (eg; purchases, things to do.). I have a low-budget, but really wants to start playing again and what I can do with the cards I have to build a deck, or find out if I can build a deck rather.

I have linked my card collection [here](https://deckbox.org/sets/766934) on Deckbox for you guys to see what I am working with.

Sorry for the wall of text and thanks a lot for reading and helping.

-S

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based. We have no way of telling you what format will suit you the most. If you simply need to know what cards are legal for what formats, then we can mark this question as a duplicate. If you simply need to know what format is the cheapest, then you need to *severely* revise your question. If you want to know what format is best for you, I would recommend asking your question on [MTGSalvation](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums).

Answer (score 2):

Id say draft.

Its a good way to get cards, you get to use the cards as opposed to just buying boosters and you meet new people.
Its the most cost effective way if you are winning more than you lose as you get prizes and if not your improving you game, both things you want to do if your out of the loop.

Commander is good but can get stale quicker as its the same people with the same decks and there all in every game.

You have local places to play magic, you just don't know there there yet. We play at the pub and in the 2 years we've been doing this its rare an afternoon has gone by someone new has not wanted to join next time.

There are tiny groups of magic players like you and your friends all over the place all with the same imaginary problem, add in all the people that useto play why might get back into it casually with there old cards and you have enough people to start a magic club anywhere in the world.

Magic is huge, reach out just a little and you will be amazed at how quickly you will have more players than tables space.

My friends has a very obvious magic tee he wares when we go places as a signal to other players. It strange how many people will politely interrupt you and ask about where and how you play hoping to get included.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what u want. If you want to play mtg just for fun then i would suggest building bughet commander deck. Multiplayer commander is a imho best format for building fun budget decks. But if you are intrested in competetive mtg (standard) i would suggets starting with Theros event deck (for its value compared to price) and expanding the deck with some boosters.

Comment: _"Multiplayer commander is a imho best format for building fun budget decks"_. I disagree. Commander is all about big impressive plays, and most big impressive cards are expensive. If you go in with Rampant Growth and Divination, you'll get routinely crushed by people playing with Gaea's Cradle and Jace the Mind Sculptor. (yes, not all play groups are like that, but many are.)

Comment: @Kevin, actually, there are plenty of Commander bombs that are cheap, because they're unplayable in other formats. Primal Surge often wins Commander games, for example, but it costs $1. (Also, Mind Sculptor _isn't_ very good in multiplayer Commander, in part because of the reputation he gained in 1v1 60-card formats. Most of the time, he's a 4-mana sorcery Brainstorm or Unsummon, which is terrible.)

Answer (score -1):

What you can do and what you should buy depends largely on what you want to get out of the game.

If you just want to play casually with friends it doesn't really matter what you get. If you like big multiplayer games you can pick up copies of the [Commander 2014](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/products/card-set-archive/commander-2014) decks to get started playing Commander/EDH, you should be able to find them at stores like Target or Wal-Mart in addition to game stores. If you are just wanting to play 1v1 Duel Decks are a good place to go the most recent one is [Speed vs. Cunning](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/products/card-set-archive/duel-decks-speed-vs-cunning) or you can get more intro packs like the Rakdos one you already got, again these products are at stores like Target in addition to game stores. You mentioned that you don't have a LGS to play at, but you should still be able to find somewhere to play whether it is at school in the cafeteria, at the local library in a study room (depending on how sound proof they are), or at a friends house.

If you want to start playing competitively there are 2 things you will need to decide. The first is where you are going to play, you mentioned you don't have a LGS, but is there somewhere nearby that you could travel to even if it isn't very often? The second is what format you want to play. This depends on a combination of what formats are supported where you play, for example at my LGS they never have Legacy or Vintage tournaments so I have no need to make a deck for those formats but they do play Standard and Modern so I do have decks for those ones, and what you can afford, generally Standard is the least expensive format and they get more expensive the larger the card pool.

If you do play competitively I would recommend playing Standard since you seem to be on a pretty tight budget and there is actually a good [Red Deck Wins](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/the-game/standard-type-2/competitive/proven-standard/576061-mono-red-aggro-boss-sligh-rabble-red) deck that you should be able to build for around $30. Once you have this deck if you do well enough you should be able to start building up your collection so that you can play other decks, and other formats.

If you don't find anywhere to play with people in real life there are 2 official way of playing Magic on you computer [Duels of the Planeswalkers](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/products/duels-of-the-planeswalkers) and [Magic: the Gathering Online (MTGO)](http://magic.wizards.com/en/magic-online). Duels is primarily a single player game, it has a limited card pool and only allows you to play against certain other decks, but is pretty fun and much better than no Magic. MTGO is a lot like paper Magic, just on a computer. You have to buy all of the cards that you want to play with, but you have pretty much every printed Magic card available to play with. I personally haven't play on MTGO but I have heard that it is a lot of fun once you get the hang of the interface.